# How to set an event on spinner

Tags: android, spinner

Hey guys I have a question about how to select gender from spinner and after gender is choose then I want to store the gender result into gender variable so, could you guys help me to solve this,

thanks in advance

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="arr_gender">
    <item>Male</item>
    <item>Female</item>
</string-array>
```

and this variable is what I want to store in after gender is choose>>  String gender;

```
    private void initGenderData() {
    ArrayAdapter adater_gender = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            Question_page.this, R.array.arr_gender,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adater_gender.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    this.sp_gender.setAdapter(adater_gender);
    sp_gender.isClickable();
}

 and I don't know how to deal with this spinner now give me some example thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct so far, now try this to store the gender:

```
String gender = sp_gender.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for every answers :)) it helps me a lot.

Comment: If it helps, don't forget to upvote each answer and select one of them as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hy, Try this....

```
sp_gender.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            String gender = sp_gender.getSelectedItem().toString();

                }
    }
```